# EF Core unit testing with IgnoreQueryFilters not supported

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, xunit, ef-core-7.0

In my .NET 7 project, I use a DbContext where I have configured entities as follows:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b =>
{
    b.HasQueryFilter(f => f.IsDeleted == false);
});
```

In some circumstances, I need to skip this filter, so I use the `IgnoreQueryFilters()` method:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetEmails()
{
    return await context.Users
        .IgnoreQueryFilters()
        .Select(x => x.Email)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

The DbContext is configured to use PostgreSQL on a remote server.

The given code snippet represents a unit test:

```cs
public class TenantServiceTests
{
    [Theory]
    [MemberAutoMockData(nameof(ExampleServiceTestsFixture.BuildFixtureForEmails), MemberType = typeof(ExampleServiceTestsFixture))]
    public async Task GetEmails_WhenFilterIgnored_ShouldReturnAll(
        IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> users,
        IEnumerable<string> expectedResult,
        ExampleService sut)
    {
        // Arrange
        using var factory = new AuthenticationTestsContextFactory();
        var context = factory.CreateContext();
        context.Users.AddRange(users);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        // Act
        var result = await sut.GetEmails();

        // Assert
        result.ShouldBe(expectedResult, ignoreOrder: true);
    }
}
```

When running the test, the Arrange section works fine, but the Assert section crashes with an error:

> Message:
> System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
> Stack Trace:
> IQueryable.get_Provider()
> EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.IgnoreQueryFilters[TEntity](IQueryable`1 source)

Neither the in-memory SQLite provider nor the real PostgreSQL database works in this case.

How can I solve this issue?